# numerical integration over divergence

Tags: numerical-integration

Consider the following function `g1`:

```
Ka[k_] := EllipticK[k^2/(-1 + k^2)]/Sqrt[1 - k^2]
k[p_, y_, z_] := Sqrt[4 y z/(p^2 + (y + z)^2)]
g1[x_, y_] := 
 1/Pi Sqrt[1/(
   x y)] (k[0, x, y] Ka[k[0, x, y]] - k[1, x, y] Ka[k[1, x, y]])
```

which has a divergence at `x=y`. The divergence is weak, i.e., the integral over the divergence is finite.

Now I would like to calculate the two-fold integral over `g1` multiplied by the following function `mz`:

```
t[x_, y_] := 2 ArcTan[Exp[(x - y)]] + 2 ArcTan[Exp[(x + y)]]
mz[x_, y_] := Cos[t[x, y]]
```

The integrals are defined as `f1` (first integral) and `I306` (second integral):

```
f1[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ] := 
 d^2 (NIntegrate[z g1[z d, x d] (1 - mz[z, y]), {z, 0, x}, 
     PrecisionGoal -> 6, 
     Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 100000, 
       Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 3}}, 
     MaxRecursion -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 30] + 
    NIntegrate[z g1[z d, x d] (1 - mz[z, y]), {z, x, y + 15}, 
     PrecisionGoal -> 6, 
     Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 100000, 
       Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 3}}, 
     MaxRecursion -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 30])

h[x_, y_, d_] := x (Re[f1[x, y, d]] + mz[x, y] - 1) mz[x, y]
I306[y_, d_] := 
 NIntegrate[h[x, y, d], {x, 0, y + 15}, PrecisionGoal -> 3, 
  Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 100000, 
    Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 3}}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

My problems are, illustrated for y=10 and d=100:

1. The evaluation of `I306` is very slow (about 30 minutes on my laptop)
2. The evaluation of `f1` yields very noisy data, despite the requested precision of 6 digits. This can be see from the following plot:

   Plot[h[x, 10, 100], {x, 0, 25}]

[image: h]

3. `f1` has sometimes a finite imaginary part, despite the purely numerical integration of a real function.

My attempts to address the problem are reflected in my definitions of `f1` and `I306`. Specifically, I have noticed an increased calculation speed by splitting the `f1` integral into two parts such that the divergence is at the integral boundaries. Also, GaussKronrodRule with 3 points seemed to perform best of all methods.

My specific question is: Are there better strategies to solve this integral?

Edit: Renamed `I` to `I306` to avoid conflicts with mathematica's internal variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your `Plot` is actually unrelated to the later integration.
Plot supplies a machine precision value, so your integral in `f1` can not be done at the requested precision.  If you do this (takes a while)

```
ListPlot[{#, h[#, 10, 100]} & /@ (Range[1, 20, 5/200]), 
 PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True]
```

you get a nice plot:

[image]

As another observation, for some reason you need to specify a higher working precision in the outer `NIntegrate` than in the inner ones. `WorkingPrecision->32` seems to help. Its still mighty slow though.

Just using default method:

```
int[y_, d_] := 
 NIntegrate[h[x, y, d], {x, 0, y + 15}, PrecisionGoal -> 3, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 32]
```

takes about 5 minutes.  If you really only want a low precision approximation you can set maxrecursion to 1 or 2 and cut the time in half.

It also helps a little if you first simplify the integrand:

```
integrand[z_, d_, x_, y_] = Simplify[z g1[z d, x d] (1 - mz[z, y])];
```

This *must be* before (not inside) `f1` and is *not* a `SetDelayed :=` .

Also using `I` is asking for trouble..

Comment: +1 for solving problem #2 and thanks for pointing out the issue of using I as a variable.

Comment: Actually, with the increased working precision, the integral `I306` can be evaluated using an automatic choice of method: `I306[y_, d_] :=  NIntegrate[h[x, y, d], {x, 0, y + 15}, PrecisionGoal -> 3, WorkingPrecision -> 32]`, which evaluates in 3 minutes instead of 30. Hence, I consider problem #1 solved.